# Create Generic Javascript/Jquery ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to javascript, jquery, and ajax and need help making my code more efficient. I have the following javascript/jquery function that works fine:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#promo1").change(function() //select menu id that triggers script on change
        {
           //data here

            $.ajax
            ({
               //ajax stuff here
                {
                    //individual values from json array


                    //set each value textbook value
                    $("#discprice1").val(disc);
                    $("#itemprice1").val(total);
                    $("#tax").val(tax);
                    $("#grandtotal").val(grand);
                }
            });

        });

    });
    </script>
```

I change my original function to this after a suggestion:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var setupCalculation = function(index) {

            $("#promo" + index).on("change", function() //select menu id that triggers script on change
            {
 //rest of the function is here....
```

and change my select to this:

```
   <select name="promo<?php echo $i; ?>" id="promo<?php echo $i; ?>" 
onchange="setupCalculation('<?php echo $i; ?>');">
```

However, it is not working. What am I missing?

However, I need to do the same thing 10 times for 10 different rows of calculations. How can I make it so I can use this function generically and just pass the "id" of the select box to the function and not repeat this code 10 times for each of the selectors, e.g. #promo1, #promo2, #promo3, etc....

I'm assuming I need to add onchange="javascript function here();" to the html code, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: I updated the original description based on changes suggested by dbaseman.

Comment: good rule of thumb if you plan on using jQuery... forget that inline code exists like `onclick` or `onchange` and use jQuery unobtrusive methods exclusively

Answer (score 2):

This is a case when you should write a little plugin. Take a look how it can look like (I did'nt get what exectly you need but you will grasp the idea):

```
$.fn.myFirstPlugin = functin() {
    return this.each(function() {
        // This is currect select box  
        var $select = $(this);

        // Change event
        $select.change(function() {
            // Do something for this select box; $(this) will point to current select element
            $.ajax({ ... })
        });
    })
};
```

Then you would use it like:

```
$('#promo1, #promo2, #promo3').myFirstPlugin();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an "onchange" attribute inline, I would use your current approach to wireup the event handler.  That way you can define a function `setupCalculation` that wires up the logic for a given select list.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var setupCalculation = function(id) {
        $("#" + id).on("change", function() {
            // ajax/calculation logic
        });
    }

    setupCalculation("promo1");
    setupCalculation("promo2");
    // ...etc
});
```

If the result elements are different (eg discprice2, discprice3, etc), then it may be better to pass an index to the function instead, and hard-code the name part of the ids:

```
var setupCalculation = function(index) {
    $("#promo" + index).on("change", function() {

        // ajax stuff 
        $("#discprice" + index).val(disc);
        // etc
    });
}
```

---

**Edit** Using the form `onchange=setupCalculation()`, the function should look like this (no need to wire up the change event):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    window.setupCalculation = function(index) {
       //rest of the function is here....
```

Comment: There is no `onchange`-attribute!?

Comment: @feela [sure there is](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-SELECT)

Comment: I'll try this approach and see if I can implement it. Each result element is a different value and I'm not always using all 10 select menus (it is up to the user for how much data is entered) so I thnk the second approach is good. I'll see if i can get it.

Comment: How do I pass the index to the SetupCalculation function without using something like onchange="SetupCalculation('1')" or do I still use onchange?

Comment: Dbaseman - will you look at my change to the original question above? I think I'm close, but the new function won't work.

Comment: @XanderNGCC if you're calling the function inline from the select element like `<select onchange="setupCalculation('1')" />`, then you need to make sure `setupCalculation` has a global scope.  To do that, use `window.setupCalculation = function(index) { ... }`.

Comment: Dbaseman - I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it just won't work. I changed it to use window.setupCalculation using the code you suggested and it doesn't execute. Should I post all my code?

Comment: @XanderNGCC I'm sorry, I just looked at your code more closely, and noticed something else.  You should use either the form `"onchange=setupCalculation()"` OR `$("promo").on("change", function() { })`, but not both.  See my edit above.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I used the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your select boxes look like

```
<select id="promo1">...</select>
<select id="promo2">...</select>
```

add a class to each one

```
<select id="promo1" class="promo">...</select>
<select id="promo2" class="promo">...</select>
```

so that you can select all the boxes with one simple selector for the `change` event function:

```
$(".promo").change(function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a jQuery function and call it from the selected object:

```
$.fn.changePromo = function() {
    /* return this jQuery object to allow chaining and execute in an 'each()' to allow multiple elements */
    return this.each( function() {
        $( this ).change( function() {
            /* your ajax call here */
        } );
    } );
}

/* call examples */
$( '#promo1' ).changePromo();
$( '#promo1,#promo2' ).changePromo();
```